# How to remove view controller stack and only show one view controller

Tags: ios, swift

When I present another view controller, it shows this view:

[image]

How do I change it so that my program only shows the destination view controller without this effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this by code,

add 
`vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` when presenting the view controller.

If you are doing this from the Storyboard,

select the storyboard segue in which you present the view controller, and on the right inspector, select `Full Screen` for `Presentation`.